# Can I use "needs of the hour" when referring to something plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

Can I say "needs of the hour" in place of "need of the hour" when talking about plural subjects? For example:

> These changes are needs of the hour.

Comment: You should probably stick to singular ***need*** regardless of whether it's in the context of a singular or plural "subject". Google Books claims 18,000 hits for [*are the **need** of the hour*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22are+the+need+of+the+hour%22), but only half that number for [*are the **needs** of the hour*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22are+the+needs+of+the+hour%22), even though obviously the "subject" before ***are*** would always be plural.

Comment: (and after scrolling through several pages of results for ***need*** in my above search, GB still thinks it has over 18,000 hits. But scrolling to the second page of the ***needs*** search reveals that there are actually ***only 18 in total.*** Google Books "guestimates" are pretty rubbishy, but you can hardly argue with the "final" tally there! :)

Answer (score 2):

Technically yes, but it is not as idiomatic as "the need of the hour." Prior precedence stems from "men of the hour" becoming accepted usage over the last century and a half for teams accomplishing extraordinary feats under trying circumstances (mainly war).

Supporting material:

[Google NGram search for "men of the hour"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=men+of+the+hour&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmen%20of%20the%20hour%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Hello, Glitch. I can't see a close correlation between the data you present and the data required. A slight change in an expression can alter colloquiality enormously.